# WSO2 WSF/PHP - Soap fault: XML builder done with pulling. Pull parser cannot pull any more

Tags: php, web-services, apache-axis, wsh, wso2

I use WSO2 WSF/PHP. I have the WSF extension compiled and enabled in PHP. But I receive this Soap fault response when sending a request to the webservice:

```
soapenv:Client
XML builder done with pulling. Pull parser cannot pull any more
```

The last lines from the wsf_php_server.log is:

```
[Mon Sep 6 11:54:04 2010] [debug] /root/download/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/src/wsf_wsdl.c(1685) [wsf_wsdl]policies found
[Mon Sep 6 11:54:04 2010] [debug] /root/download/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/src/wsf_wsdl.c(1752) operation name is Search
[Mon Sep 6 11:54:04 2010] [debug] /root/download/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/src/wsf_wsdl.c(1848) [wsf_wsdl]valid policies not found
[Mon Sep 6 11:54:04 2010] [debug] /root/download/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/src/wsf_worker.c(409) [WSF/PHP] Client HTTP version HTTP/1.1
[Mon Sep 6 11:54:04 2010] [debug] soap_builder.c(883) Identified soap version is soap11
[Mon Sep 6 11:54:04 2010] [debug] om_stax_builder.c(651) -1 returned from the xml reader when reading xml
[Mon Sep 6 11:54:04 2010] [error] soap_builder.c(329) Error occurred when building node
```

I have tried restarting the httpd proces - as this forum thread suggest: http://wso2.org/forum/thread/5151

WSF/PHP is installed on the following server: Apache/2.2.16 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8k DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 with Suhosin-Patch. FreeBSD version: FreeBSD 8.0-RELEASE-p4.

Any suggestions for further debugging or resolutions would be very welcome.

**UPDATE**

The WSO2 WSF/PHP samples works - at least when I use the samples as both client and server. If I use SoapUI as the client I get an error:

```
 Transport identified SOAP version does not match with SOAP message version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the XML builder done with pulling error was, that I had an error in my request XML. The Header element was duplicated:

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
```

Hope this helps others with this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case with SoapUI 5.2.1 and the issue was fixed with with the Request Compression setting of the default HTTP request of the Tool. Try changing the request compression from **gzip** to **None** [HTTP request Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMDsQ.png)